# On the ios inscript hindi devanagari keyboard how do I type a र्‍ or "verama" character?

Tags: ios, keyboard

As in the title this character half ra: र्‍ is used in words in Nepali such as पर्‍यो

From what I read this is formed by typing "ra" र + "halant" ् + "zero width non joiner" + "ya" य

I do not know how to type a zero width non joiner character in iOS, I am using the standard iOS hindi keyboard.

Comment: I am a native Hindi speaker and an iPhone user. I'd recommend using a Hindi Transliteration keyboard instead of using Devanagai keyboard as that's hard to use even for us. Can you tell me what character/word are you trying to enter? The two characters mentioned in the question do not match.

Answer (score 1):

Just hold down the र key and you should get a popup menu with the eyelash version to select.